# Webview contents getting cropped from bottom [ANDROID]

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, android-xml, android-designer

In my app i a displaying a webpage in webview, using url of webpage. The url loads fine but the issue is that some content of web page is cropped from bottom. How this issue can be fixed? Any help will be appreciated.
Here is my code

> xml code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/app_bg_color"
    >
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/empty_result_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

> Java code

```
String Content = "<h2>" + ItemDetail.getTitle() + "</h2>\n" + ItemDetail.getWebviewContent();
Content = Content.replaceAll("a href=\"/", "a href=\"" + ConstantFile.SERVER_ADDRESS + "/");

webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, Content, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
webview.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this use scrollview

```
<ScrollView
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:fillViewport="true"> 

  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/container"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@color/app_bg_color" >
    <WebView
      android:id="@+id/webview"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" />

   <include
      layout="@layout/empty_result_layout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" />
   </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: most Welcomw @User

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the `WebView` a `layout_weight="1"` and `height` of `0dp`.